# How to write spark structured streaming data to REST API?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to push my spark structured streaming processed data to the REST API. can someone share the examples of same. i have found few but all are related to spark streaming, not the structured streaming.

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard about a REST API sink for Spark Structured Streaming, but you could write one yourself. Start from [org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source.scala).

The easiest would however be to use [DataStreamWriter.foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter) or [foreachBatch](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter) (since 2.4).

Comment: This is a big hole in the API. Rest should be made available as Source and Sink, as it is as Ubiquitous as Json. I was a bit shocked there was none embedded already. Planning to write one for the community if I manage to find some time to do it.